# Applying same command on multiple UIElements on WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, command

Is there in `WPF` a possibility the declare a `Command` binding on the container level? Practical use would be if there are several `UIElements` that are binding the the same `Command`, it would be more managable and require less code to declare it on a container level.

So, instead of doing

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

the binding would be declared with the following manner

```
<StackPanel Command="{Binding MyCommand, TargetType="Button"}">
    <Button />
    <Button />
    <Button />
</StackPanel>
```

EDIT: I have created a behaviour that exposes the command:

```
public class MouseMoveBehaviour
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseMoveCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MouseMoveCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MouseMoveBehaviour), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(MouseMoveCommandChanged)));
    private static void MouseMoveCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)d;
        element.MouseMove += element_MouseMove;
    }

    private static void element_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        ICommand command = GetMouseMoveCommand(element);
        command.Execute(e);
    }

    public static void SetMouseMoveCommand(UIElement element, ICommand value)
    {
        element.SetValue(MouseMoveCommandProperty, value);
    }

     public static ICommand GetMouseMoveCommand(UIElement element)
    {
        return (ICommand)element.GetValue(MouseMoveCommandProperty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this style to resources:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button/>
    <Button/>
    <Button/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Update**

Try this:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="mybehaviours:MouseMoveBehaviour.MouseMoveCommand" Value="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
</Style>
```

**Update 2**

I have recreated your exact scenario and it works perfectly for me. The command is attached and it executes on each mouse move event as expected.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="models:MouseMoveBehaviour.MouseMoveCommand" Value="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Button/>
```

Comment: I defined my initial question actually a slighy too vague. I have defined a behaviour that I am applying to the button. Therefore if this command is applied directly on the button I write it as mybehaviours:MouseMoveBehaviour.MouseMoveCommand="{Binding MyCommand}". Can this be set up in a Style ? Command is not invoked If it is applied within a style <Style TargetType="Button">
          <Setter Property="mybehaviours:MouseMoveBehaviour.MouseMoveCommand" Value="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
            </Style>

Comment: It doesnt execute the command when under Style. The style however recognizes the behaviour command but nothing happens on the Button. The command works if applied directly to the buttons.

Comment: See this article, which does exactly the same: [Introduction to Attached Behaviors in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF)

Comment: Setting the Command property on the Button directly and using a style should have the exact same result

Comment: Can you show how the attached behaviour sets the command on the Button? Does it use an event?